# Como somar elementos de uma tabela baseado em um parâmetro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Minha tabela:

```
<table class="tabela_finan table table-bordered mb-0">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
            <th>O.S.</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Técnico</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Pagamento</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>18/01/2020</td>
            <td>Reparo placa pci.</td>
            <td class="tech">Henrique</td>
            <td class="valor">R$ 120</td>
            <td>À vista</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>18/01/2020</td>
            <td>Reparo placa pci.</td>
            <td class="tech">Junior</td>
            <td class="valor">R$ 420</td>
            <td>À vista</td>
            </tr>

                </tbody>
         </table>
```

Já consigo somar o valor total usando esse script:

```
 var totalfinal = $('.valor').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
  var numerofinal = el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.');
  return tot + Number(numerofinal);
  }, 0);
  $('#resulth_total').html(" R$ "+totalfinal.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

Há uma `td` com a `class="tech"` que carrega o valor Henrique ou junior. Como faço para fazer essa soma de forma separada, tanto o de Júnior, quanto o de Henrique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar a seguinte solução, ao invés de utilizar o `reduce` na classe, você pode dar um loop em cada linha da tabela e usar a classe `tech` como `key` para calcular cada linha e colocar dentro de um array.

```js
var arrTotal = {};

$('.tabela_finan > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 

   key = $(tr).children('.tech').text();
   value = Number($(tr).children('.valor').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
   
   if (!arrTotal[key]) arrTotal[key] = 0

   arrTotal[key] = arrTotal[key] + value;
   
});

console.log(arrTotal)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabela_finan table table-bordered mb-0">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
            <th>O.S.</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Técnico</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Pagamento</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>18/01/2020</td>
            <td>Reparo placa pci.</td>
            <td class="tech">Henrique</td>
            <td class="valor">R$ 120</td>
            <td>À vista</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>18/01/2020</td>
            <td>Reparo placa pci.</td>
            <td class="tech">Junior</td>
            <td class="valor">R$ 420</td>
            <td>À vista</td>
            </tr>
            
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>18/01/2020</td>
            <td>Reparo placa pci.</td>
            <td class="tech">Junior</td>
            <td class="valor">R$ 50</td>
            <td>À vista</td>
            </tr>

     </tbody>
</table>
```